# Typescript thinks response array is an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Observable stream that obviously outputs an array into the subscribe block. I am trying to assign the response to an array variable to render the autocompletion results. Everything works fine except for the typescript error.

***Autocomplete Component:***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'auto-complete',
  styleUrls: ['auto-complete.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <div class="ac-container">
      <div class="ac-input">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="query" (keyup)="filter()">
      </div>
      <div class="ac-results" *ngIf="results.length > 0">
        <ul *ngFor="let item of results">
          <li>
            <a (click)="select(item)">{{item}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})

export class AutoCompleteComponent {
  @Input() fn: Function;

  public query = '';
  public results = [];

  filter() {
    let value = Observable
      .from(this.query)
      .throttleTime(20)
      .map(value => value)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .map(search => this.fn(search))
      .switch()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.results = response;
      }, error => {}
    );
  }
}
```

***Parent Component:***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'auto-completor',
  template: `<auto-complete [fn]="apiSearch"></auto-complete>`
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public results: any;

  constructor(
    private service: AppService
  ) {}

  public apiSearch(term) {
    return this.service.getSearchData(term);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiSearch = this.apiSearch.bind(this);
  }
}
```

***Error:***

[image]

***IED Error Indication:***

[image]

I wish I could show examples of things I tried but all I did was googled. I have no idea. Thanks.

***Edit / Additions***

***Fake DB/Http Response***

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable()
export class Database {
  private FAILURE_COEFF = 10;
  private MAX_SERVER_LATENCY = 200;

  private getRandomBool(n) {
    var maxRandomCoeff = 1000;
    if (n > maxRandomCoeff) n = maxRandomCoeff;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRandomCoeff) % n === 0;
  }

  public getSuggestions(text) {
    var pre = 'pre';
    var post = 'post';
    var results = [];
    if (this.getRandomBool(2)) {
      results.push(pre + text);
    }
    if (this.getRandomBool(2)) {
      results.push(text);
    }
    if (this.getRandomBool(2)) {
      results.push(text + post);
    }
    if (this.getRandomBool(2)) {
      results.push(pre + text + post);
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var randomTimeout = Math.random() * this.MAX_SERVER_LATENCY;
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.getRandomBool(this.FAILURE_COEFF)) {
          reject();
        } else {
          resolve(results);
        }
      }, randomTimeout);
    });
  }
}
```

***App Service Converting the promise response to Observable***

```
export class AppService {

  constructor(
    private database: Database
  ) {}

  public getSearchData(term) {
    return Observable.defer(() => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(this.database.getSuggestions(term)
        .then(function(res) {
          return res;
        })
      );
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the search actually being done? Are you using `HttpClient`?

Comment: I edited the post to answer your question. I basically have a fake database response that responds with a promise and I wrap the promise with an observable in my service.

Comment: What about `database.getSuggestions`?

Comment: database.getSuggestions is calling the public method in the fake db.

Comment: Did you check your TypeScript definition files to make sure everything is as you expect?

Comment: Did you try type `any` instead of `any[]`

Comment: The following worked. public results: any = []; Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for the convoluted code for the fake db. This was a requirement for a code challenge. I could not avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Observable is not typed, because your function fn has no call signature. I cannot check it at the moment, but if you would give fn a lambda expression call signature, the observable will probably take over it's types, enabling you to assign it to results.

```
@Input() fn: (string) => string[];
```

Alternatively, you could type results as any, but that's just a quick and very dirty workaround to remove types altogether.